# Improve performance of QgsVectorLayerDirector.makeGraph() in PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis-3, qgis-network-analysis

Porting a plugin that makes excessive use of PyQGIS networking capabilities I had to realize, that building the graph (`makeGraph()` method of class `QgsVectorLayerDirector`) in PyQGIS 3 (https://qgis.org/api/qgsvectorlayerdirector_8cpp_source.html#l00169) is about *4 times slower* than in PyQGIS 2 (https://qgis.org/api/2.18/qgslinevectorlayerdirector_8cpp_source.html#l00128) (Vector layer with ~18k line features, graph with ~38k vertices and ~73k edges). I tried to find the reason for this from the source codes referred to, but failed because of my poor C++ skills.

Since the documentation seems not to be updated for the new PyQGIS 3 classes (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html), are there any recommendations to clean up input vector or sth. like that to make `makeGraph()` significantly faster? Or is this an issue tracking case?